# Increase Modal height dynamically LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I've added some if conditions in the below Modal example however when the content is rendered I'd need to scroll the Modal down.
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/

Is there a way to dynamically set the Modal height based on the content rendered?

Answer (score 12):

I had similar problem. In my case it was a picklist with long list of options.
slds-modal design specifications([here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/)) says they have not done anything to accomodate content with a dynamic height and it would always add a scroll bar.

But but, there is a hack. which worked for me.

```
.slds-modal__content {
      overflow: visible;
      overflow-y: visible;
}
```

PS: I see this question was asked an year ago. I happen to come across while searching for solution. And I found one solution myself which I'm sharing

Comment: Works perfect Chetan.

Answer (score -2):

The modal height should adjust based on the content inside - the modal content block (`.slds-modal__content`) will begin to scroll when maximum height is reached.